# Meteor templates: Overriding button click event in new template which is replacing original template's event handlers

Tags: javascript, templates, events, meteor, event-handling

How can I override or change the functionality or actions that will be performed on click event of a button in my template which is replacing original template and its event handlers?

For example:

In my template's javascript file, I write:

```
//Uses atSocial template from meteor useraccounts bootstrap in place of original atSocial.
Template.woatSocial.replaces("atSocial");
```

There is a click button event in template "atSocial". How can override the function to perform different action in my template?

Further details:

I created a template which is similar to the one present here (for social buttons) (https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/bootstrap/blob/master/lib/at_social.html).

Corresponding javascript file for this template replaces at_social helpers and event handlers. Event handlers are present here: (https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/lib/templates_helpers/at_social.js).

As you can see the 'click button' eventhandler in the above file. I would like to override the functionality of this click event as my template has a dropdown button from where user will be selecting a menu item and then he will be directed to that particular social button's site/ configuration.

How can I override this function in the javascript for my template?

Comment: I do know that you should try using `.copyAs(newTemplateName)` or `.inheritsEventsFrom(templateName)` because `.replaces()` only replaces the templates dom contents and will use the events and helpers from the original template.

Comment: From what I can tell, however; there doesn't seem to be a way to override the functionality of an existing event from the original template even when using `.copyAs()` or `.inheritsEventsFrom()`. Instead it seems to use both the original event handler as well as any new ones you add...